# deeplinking iOS with dynamic url

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking

I want to perform a deeplink to my iOS app to reset the app
my url goes https://something/en/reset-password?...
I made the needed apple-app-site-association
this works when i put in the path section

```
"paths": [
                "*"
            ]
```

but when I change it to

```
"paths": [
                "/(fr|en)/reset-password*"
            ]
```

the app doesn't open/ link to app is gone 
Is there something wrong with the paths formatting?

Comment: try -> "/*/reset-password*"

Comment: @SPatel
This did work, well no language check in the url now (except when the url is catched in the app) but its much better than *.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your path section * .

Your file format should be like this.

```
{
     "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
        {
          "appID": "BundleIdentifierOfYourApp",
          "paths": ["/reset-password/*"]
        }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Even you can add more as per your need in the path section like.

```
["/reset-password/*","reset-password1/*","reset-password2/*"]
```